# Infinite animation on transformed image

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations, transition

I'm trying to do an infinite animation on a previously scaled image. The problem is that the image goes back to its original size when the animation starts. I'd like to keep the image scaled for its animation.

I've tried to add a class which triggers the animation, or manually from JS (`myImage.animate(myKeyframes, myOptions)`). Both solutions fail.

Here's how I'm doing this currently:

```
myImage.style.transform = 'scale(4)'
myImage.addEventListener('transitionend', () => {
    myImage.classList.add('animationClass')
})
```

```css
.myImage.animationClass {
    animation: shake 0.2s infinite;
}

@keyframes shake {
    /* keyframes stuff */
}
```

I expect the image to not going back to its original size. I'm trying to keep the state of the scaled image to start the animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest fix would probably be to wrap the image in a container and either scale the container and animate the image or the other way around; note that the order of transforms matters.

Otherwise you would probably have to move the scale into the transform of your shake animation to not overwrite it. Transform functions can be combined using spaces, e.g. `transform: scale(4) rotate(10deg);`.

Comment: Oh well indeed I just put the img into a container and added the animated class to it. Sounds pretty obvious now. Thanks a lot!